# Assets v2.4 producing error when saving an entry after upgrade from EE v2.4 to EE v2.9

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, 2.8, 2.9

I've recently performed an update of both Assets (v1.x to v2.4) and EE (v2.4 to v2.9) and now I'm seeing the following error/s when I try to save an entry in the EE control panel.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: entry_id
Filename: assets/ft.assets.php
Line Number: 2214

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 212

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 447
```

This error appears to relate to the recent function added to Assets v2.4 to support adding data into third party search indexes.

Would really appreciate some quick help from Pixel and Tonic for this.

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as well and can confirm that the assets are saving correctly as Roger Glenn stated.

Comment: I had to deploy to production as it couldn't wait so have just commented lines 2212 to 2238 out of assets/ft.assets.php for the time being.

Comment: I'm also seeing console errors when using the assets module interface, update also from 2.4 to 2.9.2. http://cl.ly/image/1m2U1h1n0G1W

Comment: Also errors when trying to update indexes on any directory: http://cl.ly/image/0d323O313h3q

Comment: My bad, please ignore my two comments above. The Assets ajax calls were being made to the EE 2.4 install and not the updated system.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SuperSearch and getting the same issue, it appears that 'entry_id' is no longer being set in the settings array.

I've fixed/patched for now by simply replacing line 2214 in the `third_party_search_index()` function which was

```
$entry_id = $this->settings['entry_id'];
```

To become:

```
$entry_id = ee()->api_channel_entries->entry_id;
```